# Сервер для хостинга сайта

Tags: сервер, hosting

Я не смог найти название к вопросу.Я хочу чтобы с помощью openserver xampp т.д не только локально подключиться а везде. Имею в виду сделать сайт видимо для всех.Понятно купить надо хостинг план,Домен связывать все.А я хочу чтобы я сам все сделал сам хостинг и домен создал так далее думаю поняли меня. У меня IP статический.Что нужно и как нужно?

Comment: Купите доменное имя и укажите в A-записи ваш IP. Настройте openserver не на localhost, а на доменное имя. Все.

Comment: Так я купил домен. Тут Nameservers там мой IP? А купленный домен на openserver? Все?

Comment: Кстати, если сайт статический, можно использовать [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/) тогда можно обойтись и без домена и без сервера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Настройка домена

1. Покупаете [доменное имя](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F) (существует множество регистраторов доменных имён, думаю мне нельзя давать ссылку на какой-то конкретный)
2. Переходите в панель управления доменами (её вид существенно зависит от регистратора доменных имён)
3. Находите раздел «Управление DNS-записями»
4. Добавляете DNS запись [типа A](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9_DNS), в которую записываете [ip-адрес](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81) вашего компьютера
5. Теперь когда пользователь открывает в браузере `http://вашсайт.ru` будет отправляться запрос на ваш компьютер

## Настройка веб-сервера

Насчёт openserver или xampp, к сожалению, не подскажу, но как минимум нужно сделать следующие пункты:

1. Настроить веб-сервер, чтобы ваш сайт открывался через [`localhost`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost)
2. Разрешить веб-серверу принимать запросы от внешних ip-адресов

Comment: У меня openserver что там поделать не скажете?

Comment: @MahmudShahmuradov к сожалению нет, ни разу не работал с openserver

Comment: Блогадарю щас проверю и скажу вам!

Comment: Я могу надоедать извините  я просто дизайнер. Я тут не мог настроить ни как.Вы какой веб сервер используете? Помогите мне пожалуйста

Comment: @MahmudShahmuradov я использую nginx в linux, а у вас наверно windows... Мне кажется вы можете задать новый вопрос конкретно про openserver, где подробно опишите что вы делаете и что именно не работает, можно сообщение об ошибке приложить

Comment: Блогадарю да виндовс у меня.Спасибо за терпение

Comment: @diraria Для того, чтобы такой подход работал, ТС надо купить не только домен, но и услугу DNS-хостинга (если он не хочет сам поддерживать DNS, но если хочет, ему нужны 2 IP из разных подсетей), либо услугу перенаправления домена (поддержка DNS.обычно входит в цену в этом случае)

Comment: @ViktorTomilov спасибо, не знал об этом. Кажется мне попался регистратор у которого услуга DNS-хостинга была включёна в стоимость домена.